# JQuery ajax returns new html without class

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I have code for filtering items with ajax like this

```
type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'HTML',
    url: somefile.ajax_url, 
    data: data_vals + '&action=content&arg=' + arg,
    success: function (response) {
    jQuery('#content').html(response);
```

it returns new html code but removes classes which were added with jQuery:

```
Query(document).on('click','.filter-toggle', function () {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle();
    });
```

The filter html code is inside the new html code returning, so after returning new html filter doesn't have active class and it's closed. How can I prevent stripping class "active" when it returns new html?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the [1] the HTML prior to running the AJAX request [2] the HTML returned as `response` from your AJAX call and [3] what the HTML looks like after `jQuery('#content').html(response);` is executed? Understanding that `.html(someVar)` replaces the HTML of the current selector (e.g. `#content`) with the new HTML, if you've modified `#content` prior to the AJAX call, those modifications are lost when you overwrite it with the new HTML via `response`. You'll need to separately track & reapply your changes if that's required.

Comment: What's `Query()`?

Comment: <div class="filter-toggle"></div> <div class="filter-wrapper"></div> and JavaScript for it: jQuery(document).on('click','.filter-toggle', function () { jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(); }); so when ajax is performed it returns the same html code but the class "active" is stripped, others classes stay.